# crystal report parameter setting so that when blank equals to all

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I am currently trying to add a crystal report parameter that filters by name, 
unlike dates, where you can set a wide range to include everything, if the parameter goes by name it can only take in the names user inputted, and when nothing is inputted it shows all blank.

How do I change the formula so that instead of displaying blank when no name entered, it shows all instead?

My current formula with date selection and name selection is:

```
{transfer.type} in ["date", "Dep", "Pmt"] and
{transfer.qdate} = {?date} and
{transfer.method} = 0 and
(not HasValue({?First Name}) OR {student.student} = {?First Name})
```

I just want to change the name part so that I can have it display all = when no name inputted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you are including the parameters in record selection record selection will use those to fetch... that is what you are doing here....

So when nothing is inputted in `paramter` then you need to have all values returned, for this the best option would be not to send the `name` parameter when nothing is entered.

so your formula would be:

```
if hasvalue({?First Name}) then                // if parameter has value then use in condition 
{transfer.type} in ["date", "Dep", "Pmt"] and
{transfer.qdate} = {?date} and
{transfer.method} = 0 and
 {student.student} = {?First Name})
else                                         // if parameter doesn't has value then don't use so that all values are returned
{transfer.type} in ["date", "Dep", "Pmt"] and
{transfer.qdate} = {?date} and
{transfer.method} = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically make "All" (instead of blank) the default value and make the user change it:

```
({?First Name} = "All" OR {student.student} = {?First Name})
```

blanks, nulls, empty strings look alike but behave differently.  A visible "All" tells the user AND the developer exactly what to expect.